Sobreescribir los data anotations de las propiedades en una clase no modificable (c#)
Tengo esta clase en una api de c#. Pueden ver que tengo una validación y un mensaje de error asociado a esa validación
 public class State : BaseEntity
 {
     [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage ="prueba de error de validación")]
     public string? Name { get; set; }
     public int IdCountry { get; set; }
 }

Clase en la api
Esa clase es replicada en la  UI con nswagstudio para poder pasar los objetos en las llamadas a la api (es un DTO). Sin embargo pueden ver que del lado del cliente, en la UI, NswagStudio no está  preservando los mensajes de error, sino sólo la validación. Esto me causa problemas pues la aplicación es multiidioma y los componentes que uso en la UI no me están traduciendo los mensajes de las validaciones cuando hago operaciones crud con los componentes. Los componentes me quedan traducidos pero las validaciones del lado del cliente no.
public partial class StateDTO
{   
   [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("name", Required = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        
   [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 10)]
   public string? Name { get; set; } = default!;
}

Clase autogenerada por nswagstudio en la UI
No puedo modificar la clase generada por nswagstudio porque esta se regenera múltiples veces al día, con lo que perdería todos los cambios realizados.
De algún modo debo extender ese objeto DTO en la UI para poder añadirle un texto personalizado a la validación y poder tener las validaciones del lado del cliente con los textos traducibles
Siguiendo a chatgpt intente esto de aquí abajo pero no funcionó. Simplemente no reconocía ni la validación ni el texto:

Nota: Lo que sugirió chatgpt es crear un archivo que use el mismo nombre de
clase, utilizando partial, para añadirle el metadatatype. De ese modo
chatgpt asumió que la propiedad MiPropiedad (Name en realidad)
lograria añadir la validación, lo cual no ocurrió

 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    
    [MetadataType(typeof(MiClaseGeneradaMetadata))]
    public partial class MiClaseGenerada
    {
        // Puedes dejar este bloque vacío
    }
    
    public class MiClaseGeneradaMetadata
    {
        [StringLength(int.MaxValue, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "La longitud del texto debe ser al menos de 10 caracteres.")]
        public string MiPropiedad { get; set; }
    }

La única solución que encontré fue generar un nuevo DTO con la validación del lado del cliente y usar el nuevo DTO en las grillas, mapear sus propiedades y usar el DTO autogenerado para llamar a la api.
Pero esa solución me implica mucho mas tiempo de trabajo pues tengo que crear uno por uno los DTOS y mantenerlos a mano, lo cual no me hace mucha gracia, pues introduce muchos posibles errores por olvido de mapeo de nuevos atributos y otros errores similares
Hay algún modo de extender o modificar la clase autogenerada para añadirle solo las validaciones necesarias sin tener que crear los DTO uno por uno?
Alguien conoce la configuración para hacer que nswagstudio no pierda el mensaje de error de la validación?

Nota: Haciendo pruebas descubrí que el json de nswag es el que no contiene las validaciones de las dataanotations. Hay alguna forma
de hacer que el json de nswag incluya los mensajes de error de las
data anotations?

En esta etapa de prototipado necesito que los textos de las validaciones del lado del servidor se propaguen muy rapidamente al cliente sin tener que estar haciendo DTOs individuales. A futuro podré cambiar eso pero no ahora con los deadlines que tengo
Por ejemplo este json: https://localhost:7242/swagger/v1/swagger.json no contiene el mensaje de la dataanotation
"StateDTO": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          },
          "name": {
            "minLength": 10,
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "idCountry": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },

Saludos

Este sitio tiene su propio servidor de imagenes, para que se puedan ver en la pregunta..

gracias pero no se como utilizarlo. ahora trato de investigar un poco

usa el boton [edit] y tenes en la barra superior de edicion, un boton imagen.. podes soltar tu imagen ahi directamente...

MetadataType creo que es viejo, y ahora lo que se utiliza es ModelMetadataType
Ambos se utilizan para tu caso de uso, que es cuando una herramienta automatizada sobrescribe la clase y perdemos los cambios realizados manualmente en ella; y si es más trabajo
Puedes utilizar la misma clase State como metadata, lo cual puede ahorrarte algo de trabajo
public class State
{
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "prueba de error de validación")]
    public string? Name { get; set; }

}

[ModelMetadataType(typeof(State))]
public partial class StateDTO
{
    //esta la dejas vacía
}

public partial class StateDTO
{
    //esta es la que genera la herramienta
    public string? Name { get; set; } = default!;
}

Si estas utilizando un proyecto librería para compartir el código (el proyecto shared en blazor .net 7 o anterior), tendrás que incluir la clase State en ella. En cuyo caso, quizás lo recomendable, es que te olvides de los DTO y envíes directamente State
Ahora si tu aplicación Blazor es de las nuevas (.net 8), ahí sí que no veo razón alguna para utilizar DTO, el paradigma que se utiliza no lo requiere.

No se tu caso, pero me ha tocado ver la enfermedad de DTOinitis aguda en muchos proyectos. Están las clases de "Entidad", luego por cada clase crean una DTO (la mayoría de los casos es una réplica casi exacta de la entidad), luego deben mapear para transformar, es que es mucho trabajo, así que usan algo como automapper, luego tienen problemas con automapper. Es que tengo muchas clases, también es mucho trabajo crear las DTO, entonces usan una herramienta para generar DTO y ahora además tienen nuevos problemas con esa herramienta. Y así se sigue agregando nuevos elementos que dan más problemas que soluciones en un intento fútil que todo sea mejor, pero nunca lo es.
Y la pregunta que debes hacerte es ¿Qué me está solucionando los DTO? como para que valga la pena tanto esfuerzo

Has descripto mi situación :)

Nunca antes use DTOs , pero ahora uso clean architecture y el template usa DTOS.
Para no caer (o mitigar) la DTOtitis, el DTO del lado de la API hereda de la entidad, acelerando todo y los DTO de la UI los genero con nswagstudio desde los DTO de la api. Si se requiere, un DTO en concreto de la api puede hacerse a mano. pero no el resto.
No puedo usar la entity del la UI porque la arquitectura "no lo permite"
Estoy usando automaper Cuales problemas has detectado con automapper? Lo uso del lado de la API
Probaré tu solución y comento resultados


"clean architecture" puesto de moda por Robert Martin que escribe (por lo menos en los libros que yo le he leído) en JAVA, y ahí es donde empieza el problema, existe una migración frecuente de desarrolladores de JAVA a C# (evolucionan) y se traen sus "buenas prácticas" que no aplica a .net, porque el framewok tiene una forma simple de hacer las cosas. El DTO se le atribuye a Martin Fowler lee su opinión de cuando usarlos -> https://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html (especialmente cuando habla del desajuste entre la presentación y el modelo del dominio)

Sobre tu punto (3) el patrón de la arquitectura está a tu servicio no a la inversa, no puede no permitirte a hacer algo. Los patrones son sugerencias no reglas, y que no aplican a todos los casos, ni a todos los lenguajes ni a todos los frameworks (4) Los problemas de AM comienzan cuando tienes que aprender a usarlo (tiempo invertido), luego tienes esa configuración que requieres para el caso particular, pero que no encuentras donde se hace, horas de investigación y luego te das cuenta que si haces la conversión manual te habría demorado 2min

Luego tienes los problemas de depuración, ya que la magia la hace con reflexión que además es lento. Para 20 clases siempre es mejor hacer el mapeo manual. Pero es cosa. Para ejemplo de problemas tienes: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+automapper. Lo último para no aburrir, mi concejo olvídate de los DTO y clean architecture (ya que indicas que tienes poco tiempo). Cuando tengas tiempo haces una versión 2 con ese patrón y luego mira que código es más limpio y cual es más simple de mantener
